# Converting object to an encodable object failed due to 404

Tags: django, flutter, django-rest-framework, flutter-http

Receiving 404 error while writing the data in json format.

```
var response = await http.post(Uri.parse(url + "/api/register"),
              body: jsonEncode({
                "username": _username.text,
                "first_name": _fname.text,
                "last_name": _lname.text,
                "password": _password.text,
                "email": _email.text,
                "usertype": _userDropdown.toString(),
                "gender": _genderDropdown.toString(),`enter code here`
                "bloodgroup": _bloodDropdown.toString(),
                "phone_no": _contact.toString()
              }),
              headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"});
          print("Status Code : " + response.statusCode.toString());
```

Comment: 404 is not found.  It shouldn't be a problem with your encoding.  Probably hitting the wrong endpoint/url

Answer (score 0):

please try with below example, maybe it will help. Let me know if you need more support happy to help you.

Most probably when you return 404 status code, your API URL is not correct.

```
import 'dart:convert' as convert;

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main(List<String> arguments) async {
  var url =
      Uri.parse('https://reqbin.com/echo/post/json');

  // Await the http get response, then decode the json-formatted response.
  var response = await http.post(url, 
    headers:{
     'Accept': 'application/json'
    }, body: {"Customer": "Jason Sweet"}
  );
  print(response.statusCode);
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
   print(response.body);
  }
}
```

Comment: body will be like this :   body: jsonEncode( {"Customer": "Jason Sweet"} )